# How to get "current glob" in zsh

Tags: zsh, wildcards

I want to do something like:

`$ convert [a,b,c,d,e].png -resize 50% <current_match>_half.png`

How can I do this? Is there some variable that stores the current match? I couldn't find anything in the docs but maybe I'm looking for the wrong keywords.

I thought maybe I could do it with `xargs` but I couldn't work that out either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably write it as a loop over the glob-generated names:

```
for f in [abcde].png; do
    convert "$f" -resize 50% "${f%.png}"_half.png
done
```

Note: Nothing in the above example is specific to *zsh*; it should work in any POSIX-compatible shell (*dash*, *ksh*, *bash*, *zsh*, etc.; including just about any modern version of *sh*).

Stephane Chazelas also notes that *zsh* has a different default behavior for when the glob fails to match any files: it gives an error message instead of using the pattern itself as the sole “result” of the expansion. This behavior for this situation is also adjustable in other shells (e.g. the `failglob` and `nullglob` options in *bash*, the special `~(N)` glob prefix in *ksh*, the `NOMATCH` and `NULL_GLOB` options in *zsh*).

Comment: `${var%pattern}` is POSIX but not Bourne though. Also note that in other shells than `zsh` it might convert a file called `[abcde].png` if there's no file matching that glob, so one could say that this answer is zsh specific. Another way to make it zsh specific is to write it: `for f ([a-e].png) convert $f -resize 50% ${f:r}_half.png`

Answer (score 4):

ImageMagick tools have a limited wildcard capability. If you pass multiple file names or the literal wildcard, it will create output files with sequential numbering, for example:

```
convert [a-e].png -resize 50% half.png
```

creates `half-0.png`, `half-1.png`, etc.

If you want to match the input file names, you'll have to call `convert` on one file at a time, in a loop, explicitly or via a tool. (Alternatively, you could rename the files afterwards, but there's no advantage in doing that.) Inside the loop, you can use zsh's [filename manipulation](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Modifiers) or [string manipulation](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion) constructs.

```
for i in [a-e].png; do
  convert $i -resize 50% %{i:t}_half.png
done
```

If you use this in a script, you may want to add the `N` [glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) so that the wildcard pattern expands to nothing if there is no matching file: `for i in [a-e].png(N); do …`

Zsh comes with a tool to rename files based on patterns: [`zmv`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zmv). You can use it for other name-based transformations.

```
autoload -U zmv
zmv -p convert -o '-resize 50%' '([a-e]).png' '${1}_half.png'
```

Alternate ways to write those name patterns include:

```
zmv -p convert -o '-resize 50%' '([a-e])(.png)' '${1}_half$2'
zmv -p convert -o '-resize 50%' -w '[a-e].png' '${1}_half.png'
zmv -p convert -o '-resize 50%' '[a-e].png' '${f:t}_half.png'
```

You can make aliases to put in your `.zshrc`:

```
autoload -U zmv
alias zcp='zmv -C'
alias zln='zmv -L'
alias zconvert='zmv -p convert'
```

The following wrapper is a bit nicer than the alias above as it removes the requirement of passing all the options to `convert` inside quotes. If you pass any `zmv` options, they must come before all `convert` options.

```
zconvert () {
  typeset -a zmv_options=
  while [[ $1 = -[finqQsvwW] ]]; do
    zmv_options+=($1)
  done
  zmv -p convert $zmv_options -o "$@[1,-3]" $@[-2] $@[-1]
}
```

Comment: Wow, this is a brilliant answer.